# android:pick action in Intent

Tags: android

I am working on intent ,i have open the another app with display the selected contact list so need to pick one contact in my app and add it so my view,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
         final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.whatsapp",  "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker");
                 intent.setComponent(cn);
                 startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

in OnActivityResult i get the something Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=92]
  can please tell me how to do this?
  Do need to use the another action in intent?

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can please tell me how to do this?

You have to ask the author of the application that question. If WhatsApp wants you to be able to integrate with their application, they will provide a documented and supported API.